# How to handle redirect from supabase password recovery?

Tags: supabase, nuxtjs3

I can't figure out how I can create a custom supabase url to recover the password:

#### current url in the mail:

`https://url.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=XYZ&type=recovery&redirect_to=https://example.vercel.app/`

#### expected url:

`https://url.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=XYZ&type=recovery&redirect_to=https://example.vercel.app`/***recover***

---

#### approaches:

1. Use supabase config

- I just tried out to add the `https:example.../recover` url inside the Additional redirect URLs-Settings.
- Seems that `redirectTo` works only for `auth.signIn()`
- Got an error if I pass it to the `auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail()`, like: `await supabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail({ email }, { redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/recover' })
- error:

> Could not read verification params: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field RecoverParams.email of type string

2. use `onAuthStateChange`

- I can see the current user state after clicking the reset password link in the email
- But I can't redirect the user. The event logs a `SIGNED_IN` and then a `PASSWORD_RECOVERY` event, like [discussed in this thread](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3360)

3. use a middleware

- I am trying to use a middleware to redirect the user based on the full path of the url, but my url ends with `https://example.vercel.app/` and so I got no indication of the recovery type

---

What would you suggest?

I am using Nuxt 3, Vercel and Supabase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question. Based [on the documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-api-resetpasswordforemail) you should be able to use the `redirectTo` flag with`resetPasswordForEmail` as well.

Based on the docs you might want to try doing

```js
supabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail('myspecialemail@supabase.com', { redirectTo: 'https://myspecialwebsite/redirect' })
```

rather than

```js
supabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail({ email }, { redirectTo: 'http://localhost:3000/recover' })
```

The key difference here is that email is passed in as a string param rather than an object -- it might be clearer if you refer [directly to the source](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/master/src/GoTrueApi.ts#L439)

I'm not sure of the exact use case but you can also take a look at [generating a custom link via the admin endpoint](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue#post-admingenerate_link)

Hope this helps in some way

Comment: Absolutely. Works as expected without a workaround. thanks!